# AssemblyInfo generated code ignore with StyleCop Analyzers

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

I'm trying to setup StyleCop Analyzers on my solution which holds several projects. I am facing an issue related to the AssemblyInfo.cs file generated on every project properties. An example below:
[image]

Whenever I build the solution I get warnings coming from AssemblyInfo:
[image]

The suggestion is to add a suppression message in GlobalSuppression but I do not know the syntax, this is because AssemblyInfo does not have a namespace or type which is the only way that I know how to target. An image of what I have so far:
[image]

Disabling the warning code from the ruleset is not an option since I am using that warning to get checked on the entire solution but not on this kind of files. Also adding the `<auto-generated>`(StyleCop ignore files starting with this tag) tag doesn't seem to be the best way to fix this since I have 80+ projects.

The idea is to share a globalsuppression file disabling assemblyinfo check.

Comment: AssemblyInfo.cs is generated when the project is created, but it's not considered an auto-generated file because it's not _destroyed and re-created_ every time the project is built. You should fix the StyleCop issues in this file rather than suppressing them.